# Select all posts where its title contains 14 digits

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I'd like to find all posts where its title meets the critera below in one database call.

```
title.scan(/\d/).length == 14
```

Comment: Do you have a ORM? Maybe AR? Or do you want to use directly the pg driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.where('title ~ ?', '^\D*(\d\D*){14}$')
```